# Best way to convert URL query params into a formatted array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a URL with query params that looks something like this
`&rootDimension=availability%253AOnlinepipsymbBrand%253ADell%253ABICpipsymbProduct%2520Rating%254A3%2520stars%2520and%2520above`

I am doing a `decodeURIComponent(query.rootRootdimension).split("pipsymb")` which returns an array that looks like this 
`["availability:Online", "Brand:Dell:BIC", "Product Rating:4 stars and above"]`

I basically need to check the array and remove keys that aren't "Brand" or "Product Rating". So in this case it should return an array `["Brand:Dell:BIC", "Product Rating:4 stars and above"]`.

If the product rating is "4 stars and above" should replace it with "Top Rated" if not it should just keep the rating for example `["Brand:Dell:Bic", "Product Rating: "3 stars and above"]`. The array should then look like this 
`["Brand:Dell:BIC", "Product Rating:Top Rated"]`.

The result I am looking for is `["Dell", "Bic", "Top Rated"]`

I tried the function below and a few other things but I didn't get what I was looking. Thanks for the help/suggestions!

```
const getRefinements = (query) => {
  decodeURIComponent(query.rootDimension).split("pipsymb").reduce((obj, str) => {
            let strParts = str.split(/::|:/);
            if (strParts[0] && strParts[1]) {
                obj[strParts[0].replace(/\s+/g, "")] = strParts[1];
                return Object.values(pick(obj, ["Brand", "ProductRating"]))
            }
   })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

```js
let query = decodeURIComponent(
  "&rootDimension=availability%253AOnlinepipsymbBrand%253ADell%253ABICpipsymbProduct%2520Rating%254A3%2520stars%2520and%2520above"
);

query = query
  .replace(/%3A/g, ":")
  .replace(/%20/g, " ")
  .replace(/%4A/g, "J");

const productDetails = query.split("pipsymb");

let brandPart = productDetails
  .find(item => item.match("Brand"))
  .replace("Brand:", "")
  .split(":");

let productRating = productDetails
  .find(item => item.match("Product Rating"))
  .split("J")[1];

if (productRating.includes("4")) {
  productRating = "Top Rated";
}

const result = [...brandPart, productRating];
console.log(result);
```

### Output

```
['Dell', 'BIC', '3 stars and above']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the URL, you should split the things you want to get into `&availability=Online&brand=Dell,BIC&productRating=4 stars and above`

This was you'll be able to split it a bit better without having to remove extra strings, using something like the already provided `URLSearchParams` function.

```
let queryString = `&availability=Online&brand=Dell,BIC&productRating=4 stars and above`,
    urlParams   = new URLSearchParams(queryString),
    results     = {},
    arr         = [];

urlParams.forEach((v,k) => {
  if (k === "productRating") {
    if (v === "4 stars and above") {
      results.rating = "Top Rated";
    } else {
      results.rating = v;
    }
  } else if (k === "brand") {
    results.brands = v.split(","); // replace with ":" if delimiter cannot be changed
  }
});

// this should be what you get
// results = { 
//   rating : "Top Rated",
//   brands : ["Dell", "BIC"]
// }

// this will give you what you originally wanted, but it's not a very good data structure, use results instead if possible
arr = results.brands.concat(results.rating);
```